# User spams wrong answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38354352/1505939), "Sierra" has posted a wrong answer. Furthermore, the same user posted the same wrong answer a couple of weeks ago, as can be seen by looking at the deleted answers.

After checking their post history, today they have copy-pasted the exact same wrong answer onto 7 different questions (many of which also have the same wrong answer from the same user deleted 2 weeks ago!)

I have downvoted and vote-deleted all of them, but should I take any further action, e.g. alert a moderator to ban the user?  I don't know whether it is intentional trolling, spam, or a misguided attempt to get reputation.

Comment: Careful with downvoting all their posts. But yeah, notify a mod.

Comment: It's also not the only answer they've copy-pasted into multiple question.

Comment: On a quick look they don't look like exact copy pastes, they are tweaked to the questions  (all of which seem related).
They might be wrong answers, but they are neither spam, nor non-answers, nor even very low quality. So I'm not even sure they fall under things that should be deleted. I might be missing something though

Comment: *Spam* is the wrong term here. Spam has a specific definition, and users who get flagged for posting spam face severe consequences such as loss of an immediate 100 points reputation, and it can include suspension or banning of their accounts. This may be *repeated copy/pasting the same answer*, but it is absolutely **not** spamming as defined by the guidelines here.

Comment: I made a Meta question of this exact same issue with another user. It was closed my a moderator and he said to flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @theblindprophet thanks. I searched meta but couldn't find anything relevant, I guess because yours was closed!

Comment: @dorukayhan Reddit user detected.

Comment: @Zenadix Back in my day, "karma" was associated with Slashdot!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've cleaned up a lot of that user's posts; they were, indeed, pretty repetitive. Most of the time, such posts are well-intentioned attempts to help lots of users with relatively little effort or, at worst, attempts to get some easy rep. These posts were not really spam, however, at least not the way SO defines spam for flagging purposes.

In the future, the way to handle this is to raise a flag on one of the duplicated answers. You can also leave a comment; something like this is usually good:

> Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Please note that the system already, automatically flags *exact* duplicates by the same author. But it won't necessarily catch instances of near-duplicates.

As others said in the comments, be careful about downvoting every post or even most of them. That looks like targeted downvoting and is likely to be reversed. It's also likely to draw complaints. Only downvote if the post, taken by itself, is worthy of a downvote. Please don't downvote just because it's a duplicate, and please don't single out any particular user for downvotes.